# On the orbit of a Fréchet Lie group action

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Suppose that $G$ is a Fréchet Lie group acting on a Fréchet manifold $X$.
Fix $x\in X$ and let $\alpha(t)$ be a smooth path in $X$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha(0)=x\\
\alpha(t)\in G\cdot x.
\end{cases}
$$
Also denote $\rho_{x}:G\rightarrow X:g\mapsto g\cdot x$. Is it true that $\alpha'(0)\in \operatorname{Im}(d_{e}\rho_{x})$?

In the finite dimensional setting, this is clearly the case: the orbit $G\cdot x$ is a weakly embedded submanifold of $X$, hence $\alpha(t)$ is also smooth as a curve in $G\cdot x$. Consequently $$\alpha'(0)\in T_{x}(G\cdot x)=\operatorname{Im}(d_{e}\rho_{x}).$$

In the case that is of interest to me, $G=\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ is the space of diffeomorphisms of a compact manifold $M$, and $X$ is the Fréchet space of rank-$k$ distributions $\Gamma(\operatorname{Gr}_{k}(M))$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a precise characterization of when the orbits are initial submanifolds in infinite dimensions. In fact, the manifold structure on the orbits is a hard problem even for $G$-actions on a coset space $G / H$, see Problem IX.3 in [Neeb - Towards a Lie theory for locally convex groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06269).

Proposition 3.17 in [Diez and Rudolph - Slice theorem and orbit type stratification in infinite dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04698) shows that the orbits of Fréchet actions are embedded submanifolds if the action is proper, the stabilizer is a Lie subgroup and the linearization of the action has a tame inverse family. However, this proposition does not apply in your situation as the action is not proper in general (for example, if $k=0$, the zero distribution has the whole diffeomorphism group as stabilizer). Maybe, it works if you restrict attention to a subset of sufficiently rigid distributions.